# How to get current value of td usig javascript.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I m iterating td values in html using thymeleaf. I create my webpage such that , there are view,approve.disapprove buttons for each iterated element of td. Now when a user presses VIEW button , i need to access the particular td value corresponding to it. 
Any solutions on how to access the td value in javascript.?

I currently usee this in js. but it returns the entire list value . not the particular value.

```
 var r = $("#testing #InputRuleName").text();
    alert(r);
```

Web Page Design:

```
 <ol>
            <table id="testing">
             <tr th:each="RuleNameList : ${model.RuleNameList}">                    
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
              <li>  <td th:id="InputRuleName" th:text="${RuleNameList}" />        
                    <button type="button" onclick="sendresponse()" id="view">VIEW</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="sendresponse()" id="Approve">APPROVE</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="sendresponse()" id="DisApprove">DISAPPROVE</button> </li> 
                    <br/>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </ol>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique within document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it from the `event` object

```
onclick="sendresponse(event)"
```

```
function sendresponse(e) {
 console.log(e.target.parentElement)
}
```

Comment: yeah .. it returned the entire div tag elements.. but I was able to retrieve it.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture event at `tr` level and write condition to identify the source

change the tr and put a dummy CSS class

```
<tr class="datarow"
```

Now write a jQuery for that CSS class selector

```
$(".datarow").on('click', function(e) {
     if(e.target.value == 'view') { //identify if this button is pressed
          //traverse above the button and traverse back inside
          alert( $("td", $(e.target).parent()).text() ); 
     }
});
```

Explanation for `$("td", $(e.target).parent())`, jQuery allows to select inside an element which is already selected, first parameter is a selector string, second parameter is the previously select element

Answer (score 0):

If you are clicking on td you can use **currentTarget** => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

```
$('td').on('click',(el)=>{
console.log(el.currentTarget)
}
```

If not you can see it's properties with **event.target** => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

```
$('td').on('click',(el)=>{
//On it's properties you can see parentNodes, parents, childs....
console.log(el.target)
}
```